# Render template tags when passing as variable in django

Tags: django, templates, variables

I want to pass some html as a string in a variable to a template, which also includes a link: <a href= {%url: 'app:page'%}> If I pass the variable though, the template tags are not invoked. If I use {{variable | safe}} to escape the restrictions, still it is not being called. I think I have a major error in my thinking, or is it just not possible to do this? The idea is to ultimately load those strings from the database to show users customized webpage elements.

view.py:

```
def custom(request, slug):
    
    link = """<li><a href="{% url 'app:page'%}">Link</a></li>"""

    return render(request, 'basics/custom.html', {'link': link})
```

and in the webpage custom.html:

```
{{link | safe }}
```

Comment: How do you render the template, can you share the view. Note that it is `{% url ... %}`, not `{% url: '... %}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`format_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) to build a HTML fragment for use in your templates, and [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) for resolving a url

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html


def custom(request, slug):
    link = format_html(
        '<li><a href="{}">Link</a></li>',
        reverse('app:page'),
    )

    return render(request, 'basics/custom.html', {'link': link})
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that is very helpful, and a much better approach than what I was trying to do. I didn't even know about the utils.html function. Made my day